# Number format is giving + sign for negative decimal number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, number-formatting

I am trying to format a decimal number with +/- sign with one digit after the decimal. I am using below query

```
select FORMAT(-0.034, '+0.0;-0.0')
```

And I am getting +0.0 in the output instead of -0.0

Comment: Because `0` has neither a positive or negative value. So it defults to the positive format. If you want `0` to have a negative symbol use `'+0.0;-0.0;-0.0'`

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu for taking the time to answer my question. This is what I wanted. I need this formatting because I was just trying to concatenate multiple decimal number to the short notation and view all of them in one column and want to view in SQL server management studio result grid.

Comment: The *real* question, however, is why do you want your numerical values to be a `varchar`? Formatting should be done in the presentation layer, not the database layer.

Comment: @Larnu Not *strictly* true. In IEEE754 you can have a negative 0, most binary decimal formats also allow it. I don't think SQL Server does though...

Comment: @Charlieface This is a question about SQL Server, not some other RDBMS .

Comment: @Larnu I know, I know, just wanted you to be aware of that. But `float` *does* do that in SQL Server `SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAST(-0.00001 as float), 4) as varchar(10))` returns `-0`

Comment: Yes, but the OP is actually dealing with a `varchar` as the result, not even a numerical data type, @Charlieface . So they can have whatever they like, but this does also mean that that `'+2'` is great than `'+10'` ;)

Comment: @Larnu Huh, `-0.034` is a `numeric(3,3)`? (which isn't a `float`, but is also not `varchar`!) I think more the point: that is not a valid format

Comment: `FORMAT(-0.034, '+0.0;-0.0')` returns a `varchar` @Charlieface . `decimal` has no format property, just like a date and time data type. This is why formatting should be done in the presentation layer, **not** the the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a similar situation, using an expression (variable) as a value of the `format` parameter, was an option:

```
SELECT FORMAT(
   [Number], 
   CONCAT(
      '+0.0;-0.0;',  
       CASE 
          WHEN [Number] < 0 THEN '-0.0'
          WHEN [Number] > 0 THEN '+0.0'
          ELSE ' 0.0'
       END
   )
) AS [Result]
FROM (VALUES
   (-0.034),
   (0.034),
   (0),
   (0.153),
   (-0.153)
) v ([Number])
```

Result:

```
Result
------
-0.0
+0.0
 0.0
+0.2
-0.2
```

Comment: This is brilliant!. I was not knowing that I can use the CASE statement as a parameter. It gives the correct result of +0.0' with '0.000' however if I use '+0.0;-0.0;-0.0' as parameter I was getting -0.0 in output. Your solution is perfect. Thanks, @Zhorov for your solution!

Comment: @Hemendr `case` is not statement, it is expression - thereby you can use it everywhere, where expression is needed :)

Comment: @Hemendr A small change in the answer.

Comment: @Arvo <pedantry> A `case` expression can't return a [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type) data type, e.g. `... where case when TheAnswer = 42 then Foo > Bar ... else 1 = 0 end;`. It can participate, e.g. `... where case when TheAnswer = 42 and Foo > Bar then 1 ... else 0 end = 1;`. Ref. [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).</pedantry>

Answer (score 0):

There was a small issue with the solution from @Zhorov as I was getting double negative sign e.g '--0.2' with an input number of '-0.153'. I tried with other formatting option but could not fix this issue so I have created another solution using the CASE expression suggested by @Zhorov.

```
SELECT [Number],
case 
when [Number] < 0 then '-' + FORMAT([Number],'0.0;0.0') 
when [Number] > 0 then '+' + FORMAT([Number],'0.0;0.0') 
else '0.0' end
as [Correct-Output],
FORMAT(
   [Number], 
   CASE 
      WHEN [Number] < 0 THEN '-0.0'
      WHEN [Number] > 0 THEN '+0.0'
      ELSE ' 0.0'
   END   
) AS [Result1],
FORMAT(
   [Number], 
   CASE 
      WHEN [Number] < 0 THEN '+0.0;-0.0'
      WHEN [Number] > 0 THEN '+0.0;+0.0'
      ELSE ' 0.0'
   END   
) AS [Result2]
FROM (VALUES
   (-0.034),
   (0.034),
   (0),
   (0.153),
   (-0.153)
) v ([Number])
```

Output
[image]